# trigger event when option selected in Sumoselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, sumoselect.js

I am using [sumoselect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) plugin for generating multi select drop down list. I have total 5 drop down list using this. Now i want to generate array for each options selected. each list should generate different arrays. How can i do this.

I have found this solution:

```
 $('.a').SumoSelect({triggerChangeCombined: false});
 $('.b').SumoSelect({triggerChangeCombined: false});
 $('.c').SumoSelect({triggerChangeCombined: false});
 $('.d').SumoSelect({triggerChangeCombined: false});
 $('.e').SumoSelect({triggerChangeCombined: false});

        $(".options li").bind('click', function(event, ui) {
        obj.push($this.val);
        });
```

It is applicable for all the list and generate single array. Can any one suggest me how can I specify perticular  event of each dropdown list?

Also tried

```
        $(".a .options li").bind('click', function(event, ui) {
        if(obj1.index($this.val)<0)
        obj1.push($this.val);
        });

        $(".b .options li").bind('click', function(event, ui) {
        if(obj2.index($this.val)<0)
        obj2.push($this.val);
        });
```

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) has been deprecated. It was superseded by the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7

Comment: do you have `ids` to your elements? Also can you add the final HTML after the plugin has been applied

Comment: Bind works fine for me. But i want to bind different event for each class.

Comment: Thank you both fr response. No, the list are not having id as they are generated dynamically and there is a possibility of more than 5 lists also.

Comment: @safoorasafu ok... anyways add it.. so we can see if we can come up with a solution

Comment: @RajshekarReddy above is the solution and my try. I just want to know , How to associate event with each class  .

Comment: @safoorasafu your requirement was to build separate array for each select box right?

Comment: if the event association is done, then array generation is very easy.  but trigger event attachment itself is making me sucked to generate array. Will create fiddle for this.